# Javascript jQuery only shows Image element once in IE. FF works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a big Image when I press the small thumbnail. A simple Lightbox style script.

When I press the grey transparent overlay area around the image, the CSS and image is removed from view. This code is stripped down. Maybe missed something needed...

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".lightBobo").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent to open link in new window
        $(this).lightBobo();
    });
});

jQuery.fn.lightBobo = function(e) {
    if (e != undefined)
        e.preventDefault();

    return this.each(function() {
        var img = new Image();

        $(img).load(function() {
            imgW = img.width;
            imgH = img.height;

            var overlay = $("<div />");
            var container = $("<div />");
            // Lots of css styling for <div> overlay and container image...

            container.append(img); //add image to div
            $("body").append(overlay); //add overlay to body
            $("body").append(container); //add div to body
            overlay.fadeIn("fast", function() {
                container.show();
            });
            $(overlay).click(function() {
                removeDivs();
            });
            function removeDivs() {
                container.hide();
                overlay.fadeOut("fast");
                img = null;
                container = null;
                overlay = null;
                openImgSrc = "";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is IE(7) is not showing the image the second time I want to show it. I have to do a page reload to display the image again. It works in FF though.

When I use FireFox I can see in FireBug that the  get appended to  for each time I show the big image. And the "old" image  get's display: none; After 20 times I show the big image, I have 40 elements of Overlay and Container(image).

I can't figure out how to rerun the lightBobo function when needed. So it workes in both IE and FF.

Comment: Would you mind adding all necessary code to http://jsfiddle.net/ so that it's easier to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I changed lots of code. Specially the `$(img).load(function() { ... }` where I was having some problems. I dont really know WHY the load() function didnt want to kick the event more than one time. So I removed most code out of that function.

Remember the `$(img).load(function() { ... }` is for loading the image BEFORE finding its width and height. otherwise its 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".lightBobo").click(function(e) {
        if (e != undefined)
            e.preventDefault();
        $(this).lightBobo();
    });
});

jQuery.fn.lightBobo = function(e) {
    return this.each(function() {

        var myClickedObj = $(this);
        //check if we have a anchor or image tag
        var src = "";
        if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a")
            src = this.href.toLowerCase();
        else if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img")
            src = this.src.toLowerCase();
        else
            return;

        var winW = $(window).width();
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var docH = $(document).height();
        if (docH < winH)
            docH = winH;

        //the semitransparant overlay over the whole page
        var overlay = $("<div />")
            .attr("class", "bobOverlay") //used as id for closing all overlays
            .css("background", "#000")
            .css("opacity", "0.8")
            .css("display", "none")
            .click(function() { hideAll(); })

        $("body").append(overlay); //add overlay to body

        var loadLeft = (winW / 2) - (100 / 2);
        var loadTop = (winH / 2) - (20 / 2) + $(document).scrollTop();

        overlay.fadeIn("fast");

        //an element to hold our picture
        var container = $("<div />");
        container.attr("class", "bobOverlay");
        container.hide();

        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function() {
           var imgW = img.width;
           var imgH = img.height;

           container.append(this); //add the picture to the container
       $("body").append(container); // add container to the body
           container.fadeIn("fast"); //show container
       })
   .attr("src", src); //add the src to the image

        function hideAll() {
            $(".bobOverlay").fadeOut("fast");
        }
        function IsImage(filename) {
            var ext = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            var allow = new Array("gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp");
            if (jQuery.inArray(ext, allow) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for the long code. And finding out the answer myself...

Comment: Always good to add the answer if you found it yourself, helps out those of us who will defn encounter this problem tomorrow, haha. Also, I believe the issue with .load only being called once has to do with the browser cache... this is from the jQuery docs: "It is possible that the load event will not be triggered if the image is loaded from the browser cache. To account for this possibility, we can use a special load event that fires immediately if the image is ready. event.special.load is currently available as a plugin."

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that problem. I found some suggestions that you can enter a Math.Random() number to the ID so you never get the browser to find it is already in Cache. Or specificly set Cache to a past date so every time its loaded. The browser needs the new version. Havent tried that though.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably append the overlay and container just once when initialized, then just show/hide/append content when the user activates the modal.

Otherwise you need to do `.remove()` on each element ( `= null` is not enough ) when unloading, unless you want lots of dupes in the DOM.

I would do something like this:

```
(function($) {

var lightBobo = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.overlay = $('<div>').click(this.hide); // bind the click event just once
        this.container = $('<div>');
        // apply id's or styling
        $(document.body).append(overlay,container);
    }
    hide: function(e) {
        lightBobo.container.hide();
        lightBobo.overlay.fadeOut('fast');
    },
    show: function() {
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function() {
            imgW = img.width;
            imgH = img.height;
            lightBobo.container.append(img); //add image to div
            lightBobo.overlay.fadeIn("fast", function() {
                lightBobo.container.show();
            });
        });
    }
};

$(function() {
    lightBobo.init(); // init the lightbox once
});

$.fn.lightBobo = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        lightBoo.show.apply(this);
    });
}

})(jQuery);


// bind the anchors here:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lightBobo").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent to open link in new window
        $(this).lightBobo();
    });
});
```

Comment: That could be a good suggestion! Thank you for pointing out a possible solution! I unfortunatly found something that made my code work myself. =)